# Unable to create workflows in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I'm currently trying to develop a workflow for my site but am having a hard time. When I access the site online through the web, I am able to create a workflow. However, whenever I access the site via SharePoint designer, I am unable to create a workflow.

When I try to create a new workflow on SPD, it allows me to enter the name but it never shows up. In addition, the WFs that I create on the web shows up in SPD when I click on the associated list, but never on the workflow list on the left panel.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to clear your SPD cache. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/